# Footnote on graph title

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, footnotes

I'd like to add a footnote to the graph title. After adding the footnote, it disappears! Here is my `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    axis lines*=left,
    title=Histogram of S\&P 500 CEOs Past Experience \footnote{Hey, where are you?},
    xbar,
    width=8cm,
    height=5cm,
    xlabel={},
    symbolic y coords={Sales, Marketing, Finance, Operations},
    ytick=data,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=0.5, 
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={horizontal}
    ]

  \addplot
[draw=blue,pattern=horizontal lines light blue] 
coordinates
     {(0.17,Sales)  (0.24,Marketing) (0.31,Finance) (0.42,Operations)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help?

Comment: Try `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`

Comment: I suggest that you don't do this. It's not informative as a caption and unnecessarily far from the plot. That's what caption is all about; providing context to the figures.

Comment: @percusse: thanks for the suggestion. I was going to enter the graph reference as a footnote. Any suggestion?

Comment: I would add a phrase something like *taken from [26]* or something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by JLdiaz, `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` combination helps you here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    axis lines*=left,
    title=Histogram of S\& P 500 CEOs Past Experience \footnotemark, %% <---------
    xbar,
    width=8cm,
    height=5cm,
    xlabel={},
    symbolic y coords={Sales, Marketing, Finance, Operations},
    ytick=data,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=0.5, 
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={horizontal}
    ]

  \addplot
[draw=blue,pattern=horizontal lines light blue] 
coordinates
     {(0.17,Sales)  (0.24,Marketing) (0.31,Finance) (0.42,Operations)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\footnotetext{Hey, where are you?} %% <-----
\end{document}
```

[image]