# Footnote label in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, footnotes

I can't find an answer to this problem. My problem is similar to this [Footnote on graph title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87416/footnote-on-graph-title) but I would like to have a footnote netxt to one of my x axis labels. Like this

```
symbolic x coords={America,Asia\footnotemark}
```

But this crashes my program.

Is it possible to have this footnote to appear just below the pgfplot because when I try to do like in [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87416/footnote-on-graph-title) I get my footnote on the wrong page (not same page as my figure)?

Comment: Welcome at tex.sx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values of `symbolic x coords` are installed in some dictionary which gets confused if the keys (names) contain executable material.

In short: this is unsupported.

You can use a different approach which does not rely on `symbolic x coords` if you choose some numeric `x` values combined with `xticklabels={America,Asia\footnotemark}`. That should work.